# Android emulator not running but no crash either

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to put my Android emulators on another hard drive disk, so I followed this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDslqV9zrK4) which didn't work for me, and this [article](https://dev.to/oscherler/move-android-studio-virtual-devices-on-a-mac-5ej5) which didn't work either.

I've moved the `avd` file in my other folder (`/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Android/avd`)

and updated my `.ini` as follow:

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
path=/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Android/avd/API_19_-_A04.4.avd
target=android-19
```

### Using Android Studio Run button

It gets stuck at `waiting for all target devices to come online`

### Using CLI

`emulator -avd API_19_-_A04.4 -verbose` I only get this:

```
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Volumes/Samsung_T5/Android/avd/API_19_-_A04.4.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Volumes/Samsung_T5/Android/avd/API_19_-_A04.4.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Volumes/Samsung_T5/Android/avd/API_19_-_A04.4.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 192.168.1.1
```

and that's it no emulator popping up or error showing

### What I've tried:

- `wipe data` of the emulator
- `cold boot`
- delete and recreate an emulator
- uninstall and reinstall HAXM
- uninstall and reinstall Android Emulator

**My main question other than fixing why the emulator isn't showing, is how can I move my emulators to my other HDD ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wouldn't start is because there was some write/read issue with the external storage, I've updated and gave the right needed and it works now